# View posts and limit based on categories - custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

In my custom post, I have 10 products and 5 categories, two products registered in each. I want to display all products and limit by category, for example, display only 1 post per category.

```
<?php
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'produto',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args); 

$termsx = get_terms('categorias', $args);

foreach ($termsx as $term) :
    $my_query->query( array(
        'cat'  => $news_cat->term_id,
        'post_type' => 'produto',
        'posts_per_page'      => 1,
        'no_found_rows'       => true,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    ));
?>

    <h2><?php echo esc_html( $news_cat->name ) ?></h2>

    <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post() ?>

            <div class="post">
                <b><?php echo $term->name; ?></b>
                <?php the_title() ?>
            </div>  

    <?php endwhile ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

It seems to work well with the name of the terms, however the name of the post is repeating, does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: You want to show 1 post for each category but you query for 2. In the 'posts_per_page' => 2 ??

Comment: The error is to appear only the first post in the first category, the amount is correct.
For example, if I put to display in "post_per_page = 4", will appear 4 times the first post of the first category, however the title of the categories does not repeat.